# XML Schema type alternatives test

Tags: xml, soap, xsd, schema

How to test type alternative by ComplexType?

For example I have ComplexType "client":

```
<xs:complexType name="client">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="clientId" type="xs:long"/>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

And createOrderRequest:

```
<xs:element name="createOrderRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="client">
                <xs:alternative type="client"/>
                <xs:alternative type="xs:long"/>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

How to test laternative is the xs:long or complex type "client"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type alternatives in XSD 1.1 are always based on testing the value of attributes of the element in question. See the example in the spec:

```
<xs:element name="message" type="messageType">
  <xs:alternative test="@kind='string'" type="messageTypeString"/>
  <xs:alternative test="@kind='base64'" type="messageTypeBase64"/>
  <xs:alternative test="@kind='binary'" type="messageTypeBase64"/>
  <xs:alternative test="@kind='xml'"    type="messageTypeXML"/>
  <xs:alternative test="@kind='XML'"    type="messageTypeXML"/> 
  <xs:alternative                       type="messageType"/>
</xs:element>
```

So you always know which type you have got by looking at the attributes.

Of course, if you are using a language that gives you access to PSVI information then you can also test the type directly, for example in schema-aware XPath you can do

```
if (message instance of element(message, messageTypeBase64)) then...
```